# Eclipse Android java.lang.NullPointerException when creating first App

Tags: java, android, eclipse, nullpointerexception, sdk

Hi I downloaded Eclipse for Android Developers (https://eclipse.org/downloads/eclipse-packages/). When click on new Android Project and than Next I got these Error:

> Errors occurred during the build.
>   Errors running builder 'Android Resource Manager' on project 'xxx'.
>   java.lang.NullPointerException

I installed it normaly, just changed the workspace folder to another direction and specified the sdk Files Folder beacuse I already installed them. How to fix this error?

PS: I already read about this on stackoverflow but all the methods are not working for me and they are also outdatet.

Comment: Try to restart your eclipse. Build and Run again.

Comment: i restartet it already but there is nothing to build? I just created a project and than it says that

Comment: your adb is running? Try restarting adb from the command prompt: `>adb kill-server
>adb start-server`

Comment: no didnt worked :/